# error with pry- warning: already initialized constant previous definition of DEFAULT_HOOKS was here

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have used pry in the terminal all year long without any problem. But starting last night, every time I type pry in the terminal, it doesn't open and instead gives me a long log of errors. 
I tried several things and spent a lot of time searching but I am at lost and don't know what to do next.
I don't understand why it gives me some line numbers of a ruby file with the different errors since it usually work without being related to a file. 
The log is a bit long, but the errors get repeated. I put everything in case it was important. 
I would very much appreciate some guidance.

```
Last login: Wed Jul 23 10:35:32 on console
You have mail.
Sylvies-MacBook-Air:~ sylviecottrell$ pry
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:14: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_HOOKS
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:14: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_HOOKS was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:20: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_PRINT
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:20: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PRINT was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant Pry::SIMPLE_PRINT
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:29: warning: previous definition of SIMPLE_PRINT was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:38: warning: already initialized constant Pry::CLIPPED_PRINT
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:38: warning: previous definition of CLIPPED_PRINT was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:43: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_HANDLER
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:43: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_HANDLER was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:52: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_PROMPT_NAME
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:52: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PROMPT_NAME was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_PROMPT
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:55: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PROMPT was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_PROMPT_SAFE_OBJECTS
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:65: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PROMPT_SAFE_OBJECTS was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:68: warning: already initialized constant Pry::SIMPLE_PROMPT
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:68: warning: previous definition of SIMPLE_PROMPT was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:70: warning: already initialized constant Pry::NO_PROMPT
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:70: warning: previous definition of NO_PROMPT was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:72: warning: already initialized constant Pry::SHELL_PROMPT
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:72: warning: previous definition of SHELL_PROMPT was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:79: warning: already initialized constant Pry::NAV_PROMPT
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:79: warning: previous definition of NAV_PROMPT was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:94: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_CONTROL_D_HANDLER
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:94: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_CONTROL_D_HANDLER was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:109: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_SYSTEM
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:109: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_SYSTEM was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:117: warning: already initialized constant Pry::INITIAL_PWD
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:117: warning: previous definition of INITIAL_PWD was here
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/cli.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Pry::CLI::NoOptionsError
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/cli.rb:6: warning: previous definition of NoOptionsError was here
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1998:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate pry-byebug-1.3.2, because pry-0.10.0 conflicts with pry (~> 0.9.12) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1235:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:194:in `rescue in try_activate'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:191:in `try_activate'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-byebug-1.3.2/lib/pry-byebug/cli.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/plugins.rb:38:in `load_cli_options'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/cli.rb:40:in `block in add_plugin_options'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/cli.rb:39:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/cli.rb:39:in `add_plugin_options'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/cli.rb:107:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry.rb:150:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/bin/pry:12:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/pry-0.10.0/bin/pry:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/pry:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/pry:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Sylvies-MacBook-Air:~ sylviec
```

Comment: try disabling `pry-byebug`

Comment: @uri : Thanks, you were right, it worked! Thank you so much for formatting the code better too.

Answer (score 7):

Pry went from version 9.12 to version 10 recently, and it seems the update created an incompatibility with bye-bug or pry-nav... One of the two. I've gotten around this by reverting back to Pry version 9.12. You can do this by typing...

```
gem uninstall pry
```

It'll ask you which version to uninstall, you'll want to uninstall version '10.' If it doesn't ask you and you uninstall Pry entirely, you can get it right back with...

```
gem install pry -v 0.9.12
```

Hope this helps.