# Pry - Gem Conflict Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

When I run `pry` on my terminal, I get the below error.

I've tried `bundle update` and also `gem update pry` but still get the same error.

```
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:14: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_HOOKS
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:14: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_HOOKS was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:20: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_PRINT
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:20: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PRINT was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant Pry::SIMPLE_PRINT
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:29: warning: previous definition of SIMPLE_PRINT was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:38: warning: already initialized constant Pry::CLIPPED_PRINT
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:38: warning: previous definition of CLIPPED_PRINT was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:43: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_HANDLER
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:43: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_HANDLER was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:52: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_PROMPT_NAME
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:52: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PROMPT_NAME was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_PROMPT
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:55: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PROMPT was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_PROMPT_SAFE_OBJECTS
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:65: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_PROMPT_SAFE_OBJECTS was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry- 0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:68: warning: already initialized constant Pry::SIMPLE_PROMPT
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:68: warning: previous definition of SIMPLE_PROMPT was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:70: warning: already initialized constant Pry::NO_PROMPT
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:70: warning: previous definition of NO_PROMPT was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:72: warning: already initialized constant Pry::SHELL_PROMPT
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:72: warning: previous definition of SHELL_PROMPT was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:79: warning: already initialized constant Pry::NAV_PROMPT
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:79: warning: previous definition of NAV_PROMPT was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:94: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_CONTROL_D_HANDLER
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:94: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_CONTROL_D_HANDLER was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:109: warning: already initialized constant Pry::DEFAULT_SYSTEM
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:109: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_SYSTEM was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:117: warning: already initialized constant Pry::INITIAL_PWD
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:117: warning: previous definition of INITIAL_PWD was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry/cli.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Pry::CLI::NoOptionsError
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry/cli.rb:6: warning: previous definition of NoOptionsError was here
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2112:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate pry-byebug-1.3.2, because pry-0.10.3 conflicts with pry (~> 0.9.12) (Gem::ConflictError)
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1280:in `activate'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:198:in `rescue in try_activate'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:195:in `try_activate'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-byebug-1.3.2/lib/pry-byebug/cli.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry/plugins.rb:38:in `load_cli_options'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry/cli.rb:40:in `block in add_plugin_options'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry/cli.rb:39:in `each'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry/cli.rb:39:in `add_plugin_options'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry/cli.rb:107:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/lib/pry.rb:150:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/bin/pry:12:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.3/bin/pry:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/pry:23:in `load'
from /Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/pry:23:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What have you tried doing? It helps us a lot if you tell us the things you've researched and tried, so we don't waste time trying the same things. Also, it looks like you're trying to load two different versions of Pry. Do you have a [`.pryrc`](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Pry-rc) in your home directory?

Comment: I did mention that I tried `gem update pry` on the post, apologies if I wasn't clearer. I did check and I dont have `.pryrc` in my home directory

Comment: `gem update pry` is one thing to try. Where else have you looked, what did you try and what happened? Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users, which will give you an idea of the effort the community expects, and what you need to add.

Comment: This post has the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917565/error-with-pry-warning-already-initialized-constant-previous-definition-of-def